# Data for "Proximity to Green Space" in United States

Tags: data-request, usa, api

Is anybody aware of a dataset or API that will return 'proximity to green space' if given a zip code or lat/long?

I'm not sure how proximity would be measured, but there exists something similar for 'walkability'. In short, a walkability score will grade a location on a 0 - 100 scale where 100 means there are many shopping, grocery, park, transportation, work, etc. options within walking distance. An NYC neighbourhood would be very walkable while a rural farm might have a very low score.
https://www.walkscore.com

I'm looking for the green space equivalent of the walk score if it exists. In other words, I'd like a metric to score how close a location is to parks, forests, green traffic medians, arboretums, etc. Alternatively, I can come up with my own metric if there was a raw dataset available.

Comment: I believe openstreetmap.org lists parks and similar green space recreational areas.

Comment: @BarryCarter, thanks for the link. I'll see what is has to offer.